# Cannot login to Kubernetes dashboard with userid - 404 error

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to setup a kubernetes dashboard in a test environment on AWS. I am able use the token from one of the default service accounts to login to the dashboard only to get all kinds of errors.

[image: default dashboard with errors]

This is after I gave the account cluster admin role

[image: rbac code snippet]

Because the kubernetes dashboard and the cluster in different namespaces (kubernetes-dashboard vs kube-system), I thought that was the issue. However, same messages when change namespaces:

[image: kubernetes dashboard namespace]

Same with the Kube-system namespace:

[image: kube-system namespace]

I then decided to create a new account called admin-user and gave it the cluster-admin role

[image: rbac for admin-user]

I try to login after getting the secret for this account, and I get 404 error:

404 error

I believe that is related to using kubectl proxy to connect to the cluster. Any suggestions on how to move forward?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49992698/9929015) works like a charm..